# Questions about how to migrate an organization / project to another GCP account

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to move each GCP setting to another account that has been separated from my current account due to a change in the email domain I'm using.

[conditions]
Transfer the contents of GCP to another account completely separated from the current account.
Suspension of use of Google Workspace.

[Required work]
Move API key for each project.
Move billing account.

[Concerns]
Will moving each GCP setting change the API key value?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the process of project migration [here](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration), please be advised that this procedure only involves migrating projects from one organization to another. If you want to transfer Google Workspace domains between organizations, it’s recommended to reach out to your Support representative, please take in consideration if you are planning to migrate your project to a different organization it’s recommended to follow the [project migration checklist](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration-checklist) that cover this points:

1.- Create a migration plan

2.- Address any special cases

3.- Assign Identity and Access Management roles

4.- Set organization policies

5.- Perform the migration

In order to change the billing account for a project you can follow [this](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project#change_the_billing_account_for_a_project) procedure, regarding your API key concern I trust that [Analyze Move API](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/analyze-move) may help you to get a detailed report on warnings and blockers from a list of critical policies systems prior to actually moving your project

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the migration process. https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration-checklist

Also Follow the below one as well.

1. Obtain Source Permission Projects
2. Go for Cloud Asset Inventory
3. Do a Policy verification
4. Asses "Manage encrypted keys"
5. Change billing account
6. Assign Identity and Access Management roles
7. Assign Organization policies
8. Create Budget Alerts
9. Do Labels management